# No Homepage CMS or Footer Links on second Magento Store? Multi-Domain

Tags: multistore, cms, store-view, footer, multidomain

---

I recently added a second Magento Store to our base store.

Main Site: Transpartswarehouse.com

Secondary Site: Transdeals4u.com

---

I believe I have configured everything correctly. Products and categories have all come across correctly.

**The issue I am having is:** "There was no Home CMS page configured or found."
on the homepage and no footer links in the second store like on the main site.

*Edit*: If I go to transdeals4u.com/home2 I can view the homepage I am trying to achieve but no footer links...

I have tried several things to remedy this issue to no avail.

- I have gone into the Transdeals Store View and set the Default Pages to: 'transdeals' the new homepage I have created for that site.
- I have made sure they are the same theme and everything is correctly enabled.
- I have cleared my browser and magento cache several times.

*Edit:*

- Also tried following method 2 on this guide (http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/) Which did not work.

*2nd Edit:*

- I returned to the site the next day and realized it had changed to a duplicate of transpartswarehouse.com, So I reapplied method two of the previous guide and it worked! I have the homepage there now and it is directed to the correct site, but there are still no footer links???

I am wondering if this issue is being caused by the different URL's of the two sites and somewhere I did not specify or rewrite them like I should have to pull these links from all these pages "Home" (Most importantly), "About Us", "Customer Service", and "Privacy Policy"

Let me know if you have any questions about this problem I will be soon to answer them. I would really appreciate the help. Thank you!

-Will Laskowsky

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your index.php in the new site has the correct store code.  It looks like both urls are serving the same site.

Comment: I only know of one index.php file on my server.

Comment: So, do both domains point to the same file root on your hosting account?  If so, can you post your .htaccess file?

Comment: Sure! I wasn't sure how to post it so I uploaded it to onedrive. Heres the link. https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DC81589534AE6BC6!3024&authkey=!ANZHj4yhg3_kj3o&ithint=file%2chtaccess